# How to push an array into nested hash

Tags: perl

Does anybody can explain that how can i push array into nested hash. suppose I create a nested hash and want to push an array into key which is a value of another key and also how to access those values of array. pardon me, If i am technically wrong in explaining my query.

Here is part of my code:

```
    if ($line !~ /#/)
    {
            @region = split /\t/, $line;
            @ancestor = split /:/, $region[8];
            my @div = split /\s/, $ancestor[0];
            push @value, {$region[3],$region[4]};
            #print "$region[3],$region[4]\n";
            push @{$hash{$div[1]}{$region[0]}},$region[3],$region[4];
     }
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: You need to use a reference to the array. A hash key can only hold a scalar.

Comment: Push is the wrong word here. You can push values into an array, but what you describe is that you want to store a reference of an existing array as the value of the key in a hash reference.

Comment: @KarlRichter i have edited my post and included code as well

Comment: Note that if you want to make `@value` an array of hashes, I would use a fat comma `=>` instead of regular comma. Maybe you wanted to make `@value` an array of arrays and not an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to create the multidimensional hash.

```
my $filename = 'out.txt';
my %hash = ();
open(my $fh, $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $row;
        if ($line !~ /#/)
        {
                @region = split /\t/, $line;
                $len = scalar @region;
                if($len >8){
                        @ancestor = split /:/, $region[8];
                        my @div = split /\s/, $ancestor[0];
                        push @value, {$region[3],$region[4]};
                        push @{$hash{$div[1]}{$region[0]}},[$region[3],$region[4]];
                }
        }
}
```

Now to access the hash you can use the below code:

```
for my $key1 (keys %hash) {
        print("Hello $key1");
        for my $key2 (keys %{$hash{$key1}}){
                print("\t$key2\n");
                @res = @{$hash{$key1}{$key2}};
                foreach my $arr(@res){
                        print("\t\t");
                        print join(",", @{$arr}), "\n";
                }

        }
        print("\n");
}
```

Hope the above code will work for you.If you need any further help, let me know in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets for anonymous arrays. Use curly braces for anonymous hashes.

```
    push @value, [ $region[3], $region[4] ];
    push @{$hash{$div[1]}{$region[0]}}, [ $region[3], $region[4] ];
```